# Is this correct the rational numbers?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Determine the rational numbers $a,b$ , if , $($$2a-b$$)$ - $2b\sqrt3$ $=$ $3$ + $2\sqrt3$

I'm thinking that $-2b\sqrt3$ = $2\sqrt3$ $=>$ $ b = -1 $

$2a-b$ resembles with $3$ , and i solved something like this $2a-b$ = $3$ $=> a =1

Is it a correct method ? What method should i use else?

Comment: It is correct, but: do you know *why* it works?

Comment: Sincerely , no.I'm doing a lot of exercises , but my brain is useless , i want to understand the logic of them.My teacher is teaching me but he's not explaining the essential . Can you help me to understand this?

Answer (score 3):

It's correct, in general, let $a,b,c,d$ be rationals, if $a+b\sqrt{3}=c+d\sqrt{3}$, and $b\neq d$ then $\sqrt{3}=(a-c)/(d-b)$ is rational, contradiction. This means $b=d$, cancel $b\sqrt{3}$ and $d\sqrt{3}$ from the original equation we get $a=c$.

Answer (score 3):

The given equality is equivalent to

$$2a-b-3=(2b+2)\sqrt3$$
so if $2b+2\ne0$ then $\sqrt 3=\frac{2a-b-3}{2b+2}\in\Bbb Q$ which's a contradiction ...

For the question "what method should I use else ?" Should I say that $(1,\sqrt3)$ is basis in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ ?